# C++ Basic Program Runtime Error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am writing a very easy program for the open.kattis programming website. This is one of the easiest problems on their website so its quite a hit to my ego. When I test the code myself it works fine, but their results indicate that I get a runtime error on an unknown test case. The link to the problem description is: https://open.kattis.com/problems/everywhere but the general basis of the problem is I'm trying to determine the number of unique instances in a list of strings

My code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  short t; // test cases
  short trips;
  char city[21];
  char cities[50][21];
  bool found;
  short count;

  // read in the number of test cases
  cin >> t;

  // loop through each test case
  for(int i=0; i<t; i++)
  {
    // read in the number of trips taken
    cin >> trips;

    // reset the count to 0
    count = 0;

    // loop through each trip
    for(int j=0; j<trips; j++)
    {
      // read in the city
      cin >> city;

      // Linear search to determine if city has been visited
      found = false;
      for(int k=0; k<count; k++)
      {
        if(strcmp(city, cities[k]) == 0)
          found = true;
      }

      // If city hasn't been visted, increment count and add to list
      if(!found)
      {
        strcpy(cities[count], city);
        count++;
      }

    }

    // Output results for test case
    cout << count << endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: this looks like it doesn't know if it's C or C++. strcpy for comparing strings? static sized arrays? Not to mention not bothering to protect against any array bounds overruns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misread the description. `char cities[50][21]` isn't enough for this exercise:

> The number of trips is at most ***100*** and no city name contains more than ***20*** characters.

Calling the number of possible cities "trips" is a little bit misleading here, but it's not the number of tests (T ≤ 50). That being said, you could improve your program a lot if you separate the concerns and actually use the C++ standard library:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>         // <- Hint: those both will help you tremendously!
#include <string>      // <-

int single_test_case(){
  // ...
}

int main(){
    int tests;

    std::cin >> tests;

    for(int i = 0; i < tests; ++i){
        std::cout << single_test_case();
    }       
    return 0;
}
```